# Get entries between one date and another via a unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

If I have a column in a table called `creation_date` in the database that contain unix timestamp values, how do I get results returned that were only created between for example `May 10th 2013` and `June 9th 2013`?

I tried the below but all I got returned was `0`; which isn't correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(creation_date) BETWEEN '05-10-2013 00:00:00' AND '06-09-2013 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If `creation_date` is a timestamp stored as `TIMESTAMP`:

> ```
> SELECT 
>   COUNT(*) 
> FROM 
>   my_table 
> WHERE 
>   creation_date 
>       BETWEEN '2013-05-10 00:00:00' 
>       AND '2013-06-09 23:59:59';
> ```

2) If `creation_date` is a timestamp stored as `INT`:

> ```
> SELECT 
>   COUNT(*) 
> FROM 
>   my_table 
> WHERE 
>   creation_date 
>       BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-05-10 00:00:00') 
>       AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-09 23:59:59');
> ```

Comment: btw you can change the default format changing these variables `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%date%format%'`

Comment: my bad , those variable are read only.. so you cannot change the default date formats